# CSS a way to reference previous div style to save space?

Tags: css, stylesheet

I am making a simple button in CSS and i need to make 4. I want them to have the same style as the first one i created but with different words in them. Is there a way i can reference nav1 styles into nav2 to save on space? 
I hope that makes sense.
Thanks

```
#nav1
    {
        background-color:white;
        -webkit-transition: all .6s;
        width:90px;
        line-height:50px;
        text-align:center;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position:relative;
        top: 10px;
    }

#nav1:hover
        {
            background-color:black;
            color:white;
        }

#nav2
    {
        background-color:white;
        -webkit-transition: all .6s;
        width:90px;
        line-height:50px;
        text-align:center;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position:relative;
        top: 20px;
    }

#nav2:hover
        {
            background-color:black;
            color:white;
        }
```

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can add same CSS properties to multiple IDs, Classes, Elements separating them with commas:

```
#nav1,
#nav2,
..,
#nav100 {
    background-color:white;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s;
    width:90px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position:relative;
    top: 10px;
}
```

To change just one property overwrite it:

```
#nav2 {
    top: 20px;
}
```

But in your case you should use classes:

```
.nav {
    ..
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="nav"></div>
...
```

Comment: thanks for the help! Could you explain why i should use classes rather than id?

Comment: Well the main difference between classes and ids is that each class can appear multiple times in same HTML page but each ID must appear only once - so it must be unique.

Comment: You should see IDs as a way to identify an element in the HTML page. Classes should be mostly used to apply style to your elements.

Comment: If you wish to learn more about CSS you could take a look at SMACSS https://smacss.com/book/categorizing

Comment: If i wanted to change the position of my buttons but keep the style. I would have to have my code like
.nav1, .nav2{}

is that correct?

Comment: I would go with nth-child(). Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child . Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tpn5apLr/

Answer (score 0):

If you use `class="nav1"` instead of `id="nav1"`, you can use the `class` on **all** the buttons you want to style this way.

You have to use `.nav1` in your css instead of `#nav1`

Look here: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t05eotx1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

use commas (`element1, element2, element3 {}`) in order to apply the rule to two or more elements, like this:

```
#nav1, #nav2
{
    background-color:white;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s;
    width:90px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position:relative;
    top: 10px;
}

#nav2
{
    top: 20px;
}

#nav1:hover, #nav2:hover
{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the class attributes on your buttons.

html:

```
<a href='#' class='myButton'>some text</a>
```

css:

```
.myButton
{
  background-color:red;
}
```

all element with the 'class' attribute set to myButton will now have a red background.

Alternatively you can use   [Catalin Munteanu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636709/css-a-way-to-reference-previous-div-style-to-save-space/26636768#26636768) first solution and add a list of all the id you want separated by ',' before the css block.